# Can you declare strings as constants in swift?

Tags: swift

Is `let name = "string"` valid swift code?  I thought `let` only allows a variable to be a constant, but this is obviously type inferred as a string.

Comment: Of course.  It makes a constant string.

Comment: right. because of the **let** you won't be able to change **name**s value after setting it to "string" once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, we need to make a distinction.

> **Mutability**

You can declare a **constant** or a **variable**.

You declare a **constant** with the keyword **let**.

```
let thisIsNotGoingToChange = 1
thisIsNotGoingToChange = 2 // <- error
```

You declare a variable with the keyword var:

```
var thisCouldChange = 1
thisCouldChange = 2 // no problem
```

So when you ask "Can you declare let variable as a string in swift?" I have to reply: "No".
Because **let** is a constant and cannot be a **variable**.

> **Type**

Both constants (let) and variables (var) must have a type and it can be a **String**.

```
let thisIsAConstant = "thisStringWillNotChange"
var thisIsAVariable = "thisStringCouldChange"
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Predefined String values could be defined by `let` , here is the example and reference for further information.

The: `let` keyword defines a constant:

```
let someString = "Some string literal value"
```

The `someString` cannot be changed afterwards.

The `var` defines an ordinary variable:

**What is interesting:**

The value of a constant doesn’t need to be known at compile time, but you must assign it a value exactly once.

**Another strange feature:**

You can use almost any character you like for constant and variable names, including Unicode characters:

```
let  = "yeap!"
```

To make it short, `let` is used to define constants and `var` to define variables

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html